# I need to join 3 tables avoiding duplicates and aggregating data from 2 of the tables

Tags: sql-server, join, aggregate

I am working with some Email data and have 3 files: sent, opens (a subset of sent), and clicks (a subset of opens).  Basically i want to join opens and clicks to the Send file by SubID (a unique identifier).

Also, there have been 3 email deployments (JobID); I want to count how many times a subID opened an email by JobID and how many links they clicked on by JobID.  Here is an exmaple below:

```
JobID    SubID       Opened      Clicked?  #ofClicks
63809    44775286    0           0          0
89993    44775286    0           0          0
191443   44775286    0           0          0

63809    44775288    3           0          0
89993    44775288    1           0          0
191443   44775288    2           0          0

63809    44775490    4           1          3
89993    44775490    1           0          0
191443   44775490    1           0          0
```

Basically if the SubID is in the open file, they opened the email;  And if the SubID is in the clicks file, they clicked on it.  The first 2 columns in this example are from the sends file (though all 3 files have both of these columns).

I tried using a query to answer some of this (the 1st 4 columns), but it wasn't counting the clicks or opens quite right.  It was counting ALL the clicks and opens across all jobIDs and using the same total for every job which is not what I wanted.  I'm sure there's a way to do this with a join, but I'm still new to SQL and struggling.

```
WITH temptable AS
(
SELECT Staging_SendLog.SubID ,jobid,
( SELECT COUNT(0) FROM Staging_DailyOpens 
  WHERE SubscriberID = Staging_SendLog.SubID) AS opens,
( SELECT COUNT(0) FROM Staging_DailyClicks 
  WHERE SubscriberID = Staging_SendLog.SubID) AS clicks
FROM Staging_SendLog 
WHERE  JobID = 63809 OR JobID = 89993
)
SELECT subid, jobid, opens, clicks FROM temptable
GROUP BY  subID, JobID, opens, clicks
ORDER BY 1;
```

Can anyone help? and I'm  using Microsoft sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to group the counts by JobID and SubID you can try

```
SELECT 
    s.JobID,
    s.SubID,
    c.ClickCount,
    o.OpenCount
FROM
    Staging_SendLog s
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                    JobId, 
                    SubscriberId, 
                    COUNT(*) AS ClickCount
                FROM 
                    Staging_DailyClicks 
                WHERE 
                    JobID IN (63809,89993)
                GROUP BY 
                    JobId,
                    SubscriberId 
            ) c ON c.JobID = s.JobID AND c.SubscriberId = s.SubID             
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                    JobId, 
                    SubscriberId, 
                    COUNT(*) AS OpenCount
                FROM 
                    Staging_DailyOpens
                WHERE
                    JobID IN (63809,89993) 
                GROUP BY 
                    JobId,
                    SubscriberId 
            ) o ON o.JobID = s.JobID AND o.SubscriberId = s.SubID  
WHERE  
    s.JobID IN (63809, 89993)
```

If you need it just by SubID you can use

```
SELECT 
    s.SubID,
    SUM(ISNULL(c.ClickCount,0)) AS ClickCount,
    SUM(ISNULL(o.OpenCount,0)) AS OpenCount
FROM
    Staging_SendLog s
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                    JobId, 
                    SubscriberId, 
                    COUNT(*) AS ClickCount
                FROM 
                    Staging_DailyClicks 
                WHERE
                    JobID IN (63809,89993)
                GROUP BY 
                    JobId,
                    SubscriberId 
            ) c ON c.JobID = s.JobID AND c.SubscriberId = s.SubID             
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                    JobId, 
                    SubscriberId, 
                    COUNT(*) AS OpenCount
                FROM 
                    Staging_DailyOpens
                WHERE
                    JobID IN (63809,89993)
                GROUP BY 
                    JobId,
                    SubscriberId 
            ) o ON o.JobID = s.JobID AND o.SubscriberId = s.SubID    
WHERE  
    s.JobID IN (63809,89993)   
GROUP BY 
    s.SubID
```

**EDIT**

I added the JobID filter to the Sub Queries in case these are large tables to filter them. Should help performance

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping improperly:

```
WITH clicks as (
  SELECT SubID, COUNT(*) AS Clicks 
  FROM Staging_DailyClicks 
  GROUP BY SubID
), opens as (
  SELECT SubID, COUNT(*) AS Opens
  FROM Staging_DailyOpens 
  GROUP BY SubID
)
SELECT Staging_SendLog.SubID ,jobid,
   Opens.Opens,
   Clicks.clicks
FROM Staging_SendLog 
JOIN Opens  on Opens.SubID = Staging_SendLog.SubID
JOIN Clicks on Clicks.SubID = Staging_SendLog.SubID
WHERE Staging_SendLog.JobID = 63809
   OR Staging_SendLog.JobID = 89993
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Pieter Geerkens - thank you, but your first option gave me the same results as I was getting previously.  The 2nd one keeps giving me an error:  
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Column 'opens.Opens' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Scarlet13: My careless; try now.